# CSS styling issue on nav

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble styling a basic nav.

I would like the nav menu colour to be grey and when it is hovered over turns to the green colour with a bottom border. It also jumps around on hover. I tried to add in border-bottom: transparent; but I think it is being overridden. I have played about moving the code and the a tag seems to be the culprit but I am not sure how to solve it. Hence all the styles.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <a href="#"><img class="Logo" alt="Rigare logo" src="logoweb_1.1.png"/></a>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Technical Capabilities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Staff and Associates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products and Hire</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .header {
    padding-top: 16px;
}


.logo {
    float: left;
}

.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #70B0A8;
    background: #fff;
}

.nav li{
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  color: #70B0A8;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  border-bottom: transparent;
}

.nav li:hover {
    color: #97A6AA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #97A6AA;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a {
    color: #70B0A8;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle to see what I'm talking about.](https://fiddle.jshell.net/27e6bvcu/)

Comment: Inspect `.nav ul li` a and see if there is a css rule that overwrite it, and show to us. We can`t help if there more css overwriting your nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have define

```
.nav a {
    color: #70B0A8;
}
```

at the end of your `CSS` which will surely override your `:hover` effect and also you've defined `:hover` color for `.nav li:hover {` instead of `.nav li:hover a {` viz not a right way to define hover effect for `a` tag inside `li`.

Further you should first define the `border-bottom` and `padding` for your `li` tag initially instead of `:hover` to prevent the *jumping issue*.

You have to change your `CSS` like the `Snippet` below.

### Code Snippet

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #70B0A8;
  background: #fff;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  color: #70B0A8;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav li a {
  color: #70B0A8;
}

.nav li:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #97A6AA;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav li:hover a {
  color: #97A6AA;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="#"><img class="Logo" alt="Rigare logo" src="logoweb_1.1.png" /></a>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Technical Capabilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Staff and Associates</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products and Hire</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you - this is what I wanted it to do. I will look at your suggestions closely.

Answer (score 0):

The padding on your hover style was causing it to jump around.

Replace your .nav li:hover with the below.

```
.nav li:hover a{
    color: #97A6AA;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c1egheLy/

Answer (score 0):

So you remove the padding on hover and simply change the CSS around to suit what you need such as below:

```css
.header {
        padding-top: 16px;
    }


    .logo {
        float: left;
    }

    .nav {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #70B0A8;
    }

    .nav li{
        display: inline;
        text-align: right;
        color: grey;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-right: 60px;
        height: 100px;
        opacity: 0.6;
        border-bottom: transparent;
    }

    .nav li a:hover {
        color: #70B0A8;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #97A6AA;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav a {
        color: grey;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="#"><img class="Logo" alt="Rigare logo" src="logoweb_1.1.png"/></a>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Technical Capabilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Staff and Associates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products and Hire</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im slightly baffled as to why you don't have your logo beside the menu links too but thats simply moving the `<img>` into `<class="nav">` but then within this instance you'd need to add `width:100%;` to `.nav {}` CSS

Comment: When I add the logo into the nav it displays it above the nav

Comment: here is a fiddle to show what happens - I have used the CSS from vivekkupadhyay above - https://jsfiddle.net/uxwyqfvm/

Answer (score 0):

Replace this lines in your code

```
.nav li:hover {
    color: #97A6AA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #18961d; //Green Color
    cursor: pointer;
    /* padding: 10px; */ //Remove this padding line
}
```

I hope this helps..